# Run jasmin assembler to get .class files and convert it to java

Tags: java, bytecode, jasmin

I run this command in terminal of my project (in IntelliJ idea) and I've already included the jasmin.jar library.
According to [this](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/guide.html) document of Jasmin, it should be located in `/tmp/mypackage/MyClass.class.`
But I'm do not seeing any packages.

```
 java -jar jasmin.jar -d /tmp *.j
```

```
HelpLoader loading...
looks like you are starting from a jar-package
+ 199   help text(s) from:      /Users/apple/repos/Phase 4/jasmin/Jasmin.jar
looks like you are starting from a jar-package
language found: en
... done

looks like you are starting from a jar-package
HelpLoader reloading...
but the same language all over again? nope!
HelpBrowser: openURL jar:file:/Users/apple/repos/Phase%204/jasmin/Jasmin.jar!/jasmin/gui/resources/Welcome.htm
HelpBrowser: openURL jar:file:/Users/apple/repos/Phase%204/jasmin/Jasmin.jar!/jasmin/gui/resources/Welcome.htm#openFile
CommandLoader loading...
looks like you are starting from a jar-package
+ 232   command(s) from:        file:/Users/apple/repos/Phase%204/jasmin/jasmin.jar
... done with jars

The command FCHS has no context help file!
The command FLD has no context help file!
The command INTO has no context help file!
The command FDIVRP has no context help file!
The command FSQRT has no context help file!
The command FLDLN2 has no context help file!
The command FMULP has no context help file!
The command FIDIV has no context help file!
The command FSINCOS has no context help file!
The command FDIV has no context help file!
The command FSUBR has no context help file!
The command FSUBP has no context help file!
The command FST has no context help file!
The command FLDL2T has no context help file!
The command FLDPI has no context help file!
The command FCOS has no context help file!
The command FLDL2E has no context help file!
The command FABS has no context help file!
The command FDIVR has no context help file!
The command FDIVP has no context help file!
The command FSUBRP has no context help file!
The command FISUBR has no context help file!
The command FLDZ has no context help file!
The command FISUB has no context help file!
The command FSIN has no context help file!
The command FIMUL has no context help file!
The command FLDLG2 has no context help file!
The command FLD1 has no context help file!
The command FNOP has no context help file!
The command FSUB has no context help file!
The command FMUL has no context help file!
The command FIDIVR has no context help file!
The command FSTP has no context help file!
looks like you are starting from a jar-package
HelpLoader reloading...
but the same language all over again? nope!
```

Any idea of how this works?

Comment: Recent versions of IntelliJ include a decompiler.

Comment: Have you tried passing the filename directly instead of using `*.j`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have the latest version of community. Where can I find it?

Comment: @Antimony yes the it's the same.

Comment: Where are your jasmin (`.j`) files located? Where are you running the command from? Which OS? What is your `java` command pointing to?

Comment: The .jar file and .j files and the folder i'm running the command on are the same. my os is macos

Comment: Appears to be a community plugin - https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No , it's jasmin .jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turnes out there are different `jar` files for Jasmin. 
Running another one fixed the issue.